# Documents likelihood with Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, textmatching

**What I'm trying to achieve?**

- I have classified data (in JSON format), I want to generate a model which should give me the likelihood of new incoming data with existing classified data. (Likelihood with all existing classes).
- For example, I've classified the existing data in 2 classes. `tier1` and `tier2`. When I receive new data I want to know, how many `%` new data is matching with my existing `tier1` and `tier2` data! If it is not matching just want to get `0 %`

**Sample data I've**

```
[
    {
        "type": "threat",
        "severity": "2",
        "category": "tier1"
    },
    {
        "type": "threat",
        "severity": "3",
        "category": "tier1"
    },
    {
        "type": "malware",
        "severity": "7",
        "category": "tier2"
    },
    {
        "type": "threat",
        "severity": "7",
        "category": "tier2"
    },
    {
        "type": "malware",
        "severity": "5",
        "category": "tier1"
    },
    {
        "type": "threat",
        "severity": "14",
        "category": "tier2"
    },
    {
        "type": "malware",
        "severity": "13",
        "category": "tier2"
    },
    {
        "type": "threat",
        "severity": "14",
        "category": "tier2"
    },
    {
        "type": "threat",
        "severity": "1",
        "category": "tier1"
    },
]
```

**Incoming Data and my expectations**

- Scenario 1:
  Incoming data:

```
{
    "type": "foo",
    "severity": "cdsb",
}
```

Expectation: `tier1: 0 %, tier2: 0 %`

- Scenario 2:
  Incoming data:

```
{
    "type": "threat",
    "severity": "60",
}
```

Expectation: `tier1: X %, tier2: Y%`

**Some more questions:**
1. What is the best approach to solving this?
2. The data which I've shown here is just `2` features, but real input data has so many more fields with a different type. What is the best way to extract the features!